# How to split multiple measurements of the same sample between folds

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, data-leakage

I'm solving the spectroscopy problem. Based on reflectivity values for wavelengths from the spectrum, I build a regression to find a target for the sample.

I have 30 samples. For each sample I take measurements of its spectrum 3 times. In total, I get 90 elements in the dataset, but in fact, 2/3 of the elements repeat the existing spectrum with a small error. Target for each sample is almost not repeated, distributed from 0 to 100.

The question is:

1)How to split multiple measurements of the same sample between folds? (should I use GroupKFold?)

If, for example, we make LOO cross validation, then we have two measurements of the same spectrum in the training set and its third measurement is in the test set. As a result, we have a very small error.
2)But wouldn't it be a "leak" ?

3)Or should all three measurements of the same sample be in the same fold only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be (3), i.e. by respecting the dependence between data samples. Otherwise, if their co-dependence is strong, you might end up with optimistic results.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly?
Do you propose, in my case, to divide 90 measurements into 30 folds so that one fold has only 3 measurements of one sample, and so do cross validation?

Comment: You don't need to do 30 folds but assure that data for each sample is always in the same fold.

Comment: Yes, you need to split samples, not spectra. To implement this on sample level, GroupKFold is your friend.